# I am creating a pure API for a game in node/typescript. My game logic is in my controller, where is a better place for this?

Tags: node.js, typescript, rest, api, game-development

I'm new to typescript, node, and express, but I've got some experience in other languages. I'm putting all of my game logic in my controller and this seems suboptimal. Looking for a better practice way of defining game logic. For example, should I define it in a custom module and call the functions from my controller?

Example code:

```
// controller/game
public putIncrementDay (req: Request, res: Response) {
    const userReq = (req.user as UserDocument)._id;


    Game.findOne({userId: userReq, active: true}, (err, gameResult) => {
        if(err){
            return res.status(400).send(err);
        }
        if (gameResult == null) {
            return res.status(400).send({error: "Active game not found."})
        };

        const incrementDayResult = (gameResult as GameDocument).currentDay + 1;

        if (incrementDayResult <= maxDays) {
            gameResult.currentDay = incrementDayResult;
            gameResult.save();
            return res.json({currentDay: gameResult.currentDay});

        } else {
            gameResult.active = false;
            gameResult.save();
            return res.json(gameResult);
        }
    });
}
```